# best way to parse csv file in python with the support of pylint

Tags: python, csv, pylint

I'm parsing a comma-separated file in Python (2.7), and I'm having trouble coming up with an elegant way to represent field names.

Here's a sample file:

```
first_field,field2,last_field
1,2,hello
4,5,goodbye
```

Here's one approach:

```
fields = ('first_field', 'field2', 'last_field')
report_lines = report.split('\n')
assert report_lines[0] == ','.join(fields)
for line in report_lines:
    values = line.split(',')
    some_function(values[fields.index('first_field')])
    another_function(values[fields.index('last_field')])
```

The actual report has dozens of fields, and I often misspell one of the field names. The above approach is nice because the call to index() will raise if I type a field name incorrectly. I'd like to have pylint catch my typos, so I came up with this:

```
first_field = 'first_field'
field2 = 'field2'
last_field = 'last_field'
fields = (first_field, field2, last_field)

report_lines = report.split('\n')
assert report_lines[0] == ','.join(fields)
for line in report_lines:
    values = line.split(',')
    some_function(values[fields.index(first_field)])
    another_function(values[fields.index(last_field)])
```

I prefer the second approach because misspelled field names will be caught at pylint-time instead of at runtime. The problem is that at the top (i.e. in the first 4 lines of the second approach) I have to type every field name three times instead of once.

Also, in both approaches, typing out fields.index(...) for every field access isn't ideal.

Again, the actual report has many many fields, and the code which parses them is fairly involved (and it makes many references to many different fields). So I'm looking for an elegant combination of the above two approaches, or another approach that I may have missed. I just need a way to declare fields and then access them such that misspelled field names are caught at pylint-time not at runtime.

Note that I looked in Python's csv module but didn't see anything that would solve this particular problem, but I certainly may have missed something.